# Кульок у значенні пакет - нормативне слово?

Tags: значення-слів

Натрапила на одному із сайтів на цікаву статтю ["Чому шарудить кульок?"](http://krasalife.ru/rizne/znannja/2954-chomu-sharudit-paket.html). Не думала, що таке слово існує у значенні пакету. Знову звернулася у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kuljok), там знайшла статтю "кульок", однак у такому значенні:

> **КУЛЬО́К**, лька, чол., мн. кульки, кульків. Те саме, що кулик, тобто птах.

Отже, чи нормативно таки вживати цю лексему, чи, можливо, це якесь лише розмовне або діалектне слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поглянувши у [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kuljok) знаходимо:

> **КУЛЬО́К**, лька, чол., мн. кульки, кульків. Те саме, що **кулик**.

Переходимо за відсиланням:

> **КУ́ЛИК**, а, чол.
>   1. Зменш. до куль. На покрівлі дома чорніли дірки, стриміли розкудлані кулики, підняті вітром (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 92); — Полола і копати помагала [Галина Петрівна]. А недавно кулики на полі розставляла (Павло Автомонов, Коли розлучаються двоє, 1959, 124).
>
> 2. *Маленький мішечок.* На вітряку її чекав кулик заробленого зерна, і він мав сильнішу владу над нею, аніж уся передвесняна краса (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 151).

В українській мові, [пакет](http://sum.in.ua/s/paket)-це паперовий виріб, а [кульок](http://vistapaket.com.ua/uk/information/news/scho-take-paket) - виріб з поліетилену і його нормативно вживати в українській мові.

Comment: Ой, я щось не побачила отого другого значення( Дякую!